# How can a make a sproc execute without a transaction?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, t-sql, delete-row

I have a clean up process that needs to delete around 8 million rows in a table each day (sometimes more). This process is written in C#, and uses SMO to query the schema for table indexes, disabling them before executing an sproc that deletes in batches of 500K rows.

My problem is that the entire operation is living inside a transaction. The sproc is executed inside a TransactionScope that's configured with the TransactionScopeOption.Suppress (this runs along other things that each start a new TransactionScope), which I thought would not allow a Transaction, and there are explicit commit points inside the sproc.

The C# part of the process could be summarized as this:

```
        try {
            DisableIndexes(table);
            CleanTable(table);
        }
        finally {
            RebuildIndexes(table);
        }
```

And the sproc has a loop inside that's basically:

```
DECLARE @rowCount bigint = 1

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

WHILE @rowCount <> 0 BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (@rowsPerBatch) Table 
    WHERE
        ID <= @maxID 

    SET @rowCount = @@rowcount
END
```

Last night this process timed out half an hour after it started, took half an hour to rollback, and another half hour of index rebuilding...too much down time for zero work...=(

**Update:** I've run the process on a small sample database (and with a small timeout), and it's not as I thought. Evidently the process is correctly removing rows and making progress as I want. Still, the log is getting consumed. As I'm in the SIMPLE database mode, shouldn't the log not grow in this case? Or is the deletion sproc so 'fast', that I'm not giving the process that actually deletes rows the time it needs to keep the log clean?

Comment: Why do you use begin tran / commit in your SP??

Comment: Because I wanted to force the delete to be in a single transaction. I think its a leftover of my troubleshooting the main issue here, that the whole sproc runs inside a single transaction...I'll remove it and see what happens (again).

Comment: What are you using to execute your SQL Batch SqlCommand? Some data access framework? We have to blame something, because TransactionScopeOption.Suppress should work... but it depends on the framework not spoiling it.

Comment: As I was using SMO to get the index names to disable, I'm using SMO's Database.ExecuteNonQuery() to do the 'EXEC dbo.CleanTable'.

Comment: Try using something else to execute it. Perhaps SMO is responsible for the "hidden transaction". Perhaps you can also make transaction log backups inside your process to control the log size.

Comment: I'm in the Simple backup mode, so probably cannot do backup logs. Still it is strange that the log grows when I'm not explicitly starting a Transaction. At most, the last delete batch should be rolled back...it's my thinking correct?

Comment: Can you not delete the rows in batches (from the app layer)?

Comment: Probably, but I would like to know what's going on here...=(

Comment: Are you using Enterprise Edition? This sounds like a good place to use partitioning, partition the data so that everything that's going to be deleted is in one partition and then switch it out and truncate it. But partitioning is not available in the cheaper editions.

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using Enterprise (I've explored the idea before, but was heartbroken when found out I couldn't use the feature =( ).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your circumstances you may be able to use partitioned views instead of partitioned tables. Something like:

```
create table A
(
    X int,
    Y int,
    Z varchar(300),
    primary key (X,Y),
    check (X = 1)
)

create table B
(
    X int,
    Y int,
    Z varchar(300),
    primary key (X,Y),
    check (X = 2)
)

create table C
(
    X int,
    Y int,
    Z varchar(300),
    primary key (X,Y),
    check (X = 3)
)

go

create view ABC
as
select * from A
union all
select * from B
union all
select * from C

go

insert abc (x,y,z)
values (1,4,'test')

insert abc (x,y,z)
values (2,99,'test'), (3,123,'test')

insert abc (x,y,z)
values (3,15125,'test')

select * from abc

truncate table c

select * from abc
```

Comment: Aha! That's interesting...worth investigating, thanks. Still would want to know why the log gets consumed during my cleanup process...maybe the question has morphed into another question?

Comment: If you want to understand more about the transaction log then I recommend this movie: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg313762.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you want is an [automatic sliding window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and partitioned tables.

Comment: Isn't that option available only on the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server? I've discarded that, as regrettably, I'm on Standard and probably would not be able to get Enterprise. =(